# C - pointing members of array of struct into another array ( no duplicate struct data just point to it )

Tags: c

I have two identical arrays of struct  , one  in reverse order. 
The problem is that i don't want duplicate the same data  into the two arrays ,  i would a reversed array with elements pointing elements of the first array in a way that i can edit the members of struct of first array or from the reversed array taking effect in both.

you can view the source and run it online here  https://onlinegdb.com/SJbepdWxS

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct point{
    int id;
    float x,y,z;
} point;

void printPoints(point *pts,int len){
    int i = 0;
    while (pts !=NULL && i < len){
        printf("id %d x %f y%f z %f\n",pts->id,pts->x,pts->y,pts->z);
        pts++;
        i++;
    }
}
void translatePoints(point *pts,int len,float t){
    int i = 0;
    while (pts !=NULL && i < len){

        pts->x = pts->x + t;
        pts->y = pts->y + t;
        pts->z = pts->z + t;

        pts++;
        i++;
    }
}

void reversePoints(point *pts, int len, point *rev){
    int i = 0;
    int j = len;
    while (i < len){
        j=len-i-1;
        rev[j]=pts[i];
        i++;
    }
}

int main()
{

    int i;

    int t1=200;
    int t2=300;

    int len=3;
    point points[len];
    point rev_points[len];


    for(i=0; i<len ; i++){
        points[i].id=i;
        points[i].x=10+i;
        points[i].y=20+i;
        points[i].z=30+i;
    }


    //point * pts = points;
    printf("\nprint points \n\n");
    printPoints(points,len);
    printf("\ntranslate points %d...\n\n",t1);
    translatePoints(points,len,t1);
    printf("\nprint points\n\n");

    printf("\nreverse points to rev_points\n");
    reversePoints(points,len,rev_points);

    printf("\nprint rev_points \n\n");
    printPoints(rev_points,len);

    printf("\ntranslate rev_points %d...\n\n",t2);
    translatePoints(rev_points,len,t2);

    printf("\nprint rev_points\n\n");
    printPoints(rev_points,len);

    printf("\nprint points\n\n");
    printPoints(points,len);

    return 0;

}
```

I expect that struct values of both arrays change when i change value in one of the two array.

But changing values of struct in the first array ,  the second array not changes and the other way around.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make much sense to just have the same array in reverse order. Why not just iterate in reverse if necessary? In any case, you want an array of `points*` using pointers.

Comment: If you're going to avoid duplication, your second array would need to be an array of pointers to the values in the first array.  If both arrays must be arrays of structures, then you're stuck with replicating the data (unless, I suppose, every entry in the structures is a pointer — then you could make the elements of both the arrays point to the same data).  But this seems to be something of an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).  What are you trying to do that you think the reversed array is a good idea but copying the data is not?

Comment: Yes , using a function to reverse an array  do not have sense but the problem is not the function , but how to use an array of points* .  In reality in would use function to sort structures by x or y or z  without replicating data.  an example on how to use pointer arrays will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way to look at this is a set of points and two permutations on the set. This sets up a `points` array, which is used as a set, and `forward_points` and `reverse_points` as arrays of pointers to the `point` array that we are going to use as permutations.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Point {
    int id;
    float x,y,z;
};

/* Print a point. */
static void printPoint(struct Point *point) {
    printf("id %d x %f y%f z %f\n",point->id,point->x,point->y,point->z);
}

/* These print out an array of pointers to point. */
static void printPointsRef(struct Point **ref, int len) {
    struct Point **end = ref + len;
    while(ref < end) printPoint(*(ref++));
}

/* This translates all the `pts` up to `len` by `(1,1,1)*t`. */
static void translatePoints(struct Point *pts, int len, float t) {
    struct Point *end = pts + len;
    while(pts < end) {

        pts->x = pts->x + t;
        pts->y = pts->y + t;
        pts->z = pts->z + t;

        pts++;
    }
}

/* Helper function to `main`. */
static void printPoints(struct Point **forward_points,
    struct Point **reverse_points, int len) {
    printf("print points\nprint points forward:\n");
    printPointsRef(forward_points,len);
    printf("print points reverse:\n");
    printPointsRef(reverse_points,len);
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    const int len = 3;

    /* This is the actual points structure. */
    struct Point points[len];

    /* These are arrays of pointers to points; they are
     permutations of `points`. */
    struct Point *forward_points[len], *reverse_points[len];

    int i;

    const int t1=200;

    for(i=0; i<len; i++) {

        /* Initialise element `i` of `points`. */
        points[i].id=i;
        points[i].x=10+i;
        points[i].y=20+i;
        points[i].z=30+i;

        /* Initialise element `i` of `forward_points`
         to point to `points[i]`, and `backward_points`
         to point the other way (it doesn't matter that
         the backwards points are uninitialised, they
         will be.) */
        forward_points[i] = &points[i];
        reverse_points[i] = &points[len - 1 - i];
    }

    printPoints(forward_points, reverse_points, len);

    /* Translation is a vector space operation and doesn't
     care about order; we just do it on the original points. */
    printf("translate points %d...\n\n",t1);
    translatePoints(points,len,t1);

    printPoints(forward_points, reverse_points, len);

    return 0;

}
```

[image: Schematic of the code.]

Of course, there is no integrity constraints on the pointers; nothing stopping one from pointing at anything, null, the same elements, or anything else.

Answer (score -1):

I added an other struct with one element that is a pointer

```
typedef struct ptr_point{
    point * p;
} ptr_point;
```

I edited the function reversePoints

```
void reversePoints(point *pts, int len, ptr_point *rev){

    // This function is used only to test pointers 

    int i = 0;
    int j = len;

    while (i < len){
        j=len-i-1;
        rev[j].p = &pts[i];
        i++;
    }
}
```

and added another function to print ptr_points

```
void printPtrPoints(ptr_point *pts,int len){
    int i = 0;
    while (i < len){
        printf("id %d x %f y%f z %f\n",pts->p->id,pts->p->x,pts->p->y,pts->p->z);
        pts++;
        i++;
    }
}
```

and declaring the second array as ptr_point array

```
ptr_point rev_points[len];
```

In conclusion :  now data in the second array are not replicated but pointing to element structure of the first array.

The need to not replicate data arise in presence of millions of coordinate points that if replicate more than one time , sorting it for example by x, y, z and so on , occupe much memory  with the difficulty of managing .

This fix  however forces me to use structures->type in order to change the access mode to read or set values.

I don't know if this is the best solution but it has solved the problem for not duplicate the data.

you can run the source with fixes  here:  https://onlinegdb.com/SknP_i-eS

Thank you all for the advice.

Comment: A whole new struct just to hold a pointer? That's not necessary and just adds confusion!

Comment: A `struct` to hold a pointer generally indicates a design mis-step. This solution solves the problem, but is overly complex.